# How can I add the user background into the app as a translucent background in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, background

I want to know if its possible to have the user set background as the actual app background in iOS 7; similarly to how Newsstand gives the user background as a translucent element when one doesn't have any magazines set in it.

Comment: Be aware that iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA, which restricts you from talking about them outside of the official Apple Developers forum. This might be why you will not get any answers for your question.

Answer (score 2):

In the plist set `UIApplicationIsOpaque` to `NO` (false), then set, `self.window.opaque = NO` and `self.window.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor`.

Lastly set all view controllers you want to show background to default color (clear), this will show the background not give it the blur effect, that's a different story.

I will warn you, it works like a charm, but a lot of developers are experiencing an issue, that plist property is not being validated and a solution hasn't been found/posted yet. So for personal apps it's cool, for submitting apps you might have to wait or possibly just not do it for now.

Comment: whats the different story my good sir? For adding the blur effect... this is virtually all we need to finish the app with some nice charm.
Please Reply ASAP

Regards from the app team, UK HQ.

Comment: Not sure if Apple changed something, but it didn't work for me on iOS 7.0.6. It showed up only black.

Comment: Just an update to anyone follows this link, I tested this solution today with iOS 8.2 beta, it doesn't work.