# How can an iOS 7 App make itself transparent to see a user's home screen image?

Tags: ios

I've seen some apps for example (Vesper, or iPad's reminders app) make use of a user's home screen background image.  How is that possible?

It must be some sort of clever trick to make a transparent View or Window or (Gulp!) Private API?

Anyone hazard a guess?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714305/how-can-i-add-the-user-background-into-the-app-as-a-translucent-background-in-io (interesting part: that one is -2, this one is +7)

Comment: Because he posted the question while SDK was still under NDA/Beta. And there are pretty pics here.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not responsible for enforcing any form of NDAs, so questions shouldn't be downvoted for it.

Comment: In iOS 13, this is finally possible! See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592568/7840155

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I hear that the private method `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _setApplicationIsOpaque: NO]` may do what you're after.

Comment: I can confirm that this method does work. Though I kinda doubt that's what the above apps are using (Apple doesn't typically take kindly to private API usage).

Comment: Turns out UIApplicationIsOpaque in info.plist has the same affect (and, I'm betting, same likelihood of being rejected).

Comment: Also you have to add one more thing: The view you are in must have backgroundcolor = clearcolor and for all superviews that are behind it.

Comment: Really wish this wasn't a private API, it is such a good effect and so prevalent in the iOS7 apps! It would make our apps so much more unified with the OS if they allowed it. Also, don't forget to remove any colouring for the window in AppDelegate if you let it auto generate, by default it is white.

Comment: I just notice the above app has removed this effect.  They instead use the default wall paper(galaxy pic) and blurred it instead for maximum probability that someone is still using that BG. hahah.

Comment: Just an update on iOS 8.2 beta, this solution doesn't work any more

Comment: @TonnyXu Have they removed the method or does it fail silently?

Comment: @Simon, I don't know if they removed this method or not, but if you use this method, it just fails silently. I've tested this on all the simulators and devices I have

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13 beta 1 supports setting UIApplicationIsOpaque to NO in Info.plist. But, it’s not documented so it will maybe be removed or not allowed on the App Store.