# How to make Background view translucent to home screen of ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview

Im creating an application in which i want my background screen translucent to ipad home screen as similar to ios 7 reminder app.

[image: similar to this image]

**what i already tried:**

1.I tried to decrease alpha value of background view.

2.I tried to decrease alpha value of window.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, build-in apps sometimes use private method and APIs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an iOS 7 App make itself transparent to see a user's home screen image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019031/how-can-an-ios-7-app-make-itself-transparent-to-see-a-users-home-screen-image)

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect and study the source code of [ILTranslucentView](https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView).

Comment: hey that one is for subViews i want to make my main View translucent to home screen of ipad,Means if we make it translucent background of ipad home screen should reflect on background of application

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a private method. 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _setApplicationIsOpaque: NO];
Give it a try.
Don't forget to clear the background of your view.

Comment: I haven't tried using private method but unless you don't want to submit your app to appstore, just never messing around with private methods, your app will be rejected for sure.

Comment: @Thanh-NhonNGUYEN Yes Apple don't like use of Private methods. wali still if you feel to use. have a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/justin/25fa4ec47124b6c7c645

Comment: @walinaqvi Appple has removed the ability to use this api in 7.0.3. What a shame.