# User Wallpaper as Background

Tags: ios, transparency, blur

I'd like to get the user wallpaper as background with blurred effect in iOS 8, I know that a lot of people asked the same thing, but I hope there's a way to do it.

I tried to use the method of the clear background color, but it doesn't work, there is just a black background.

I'd like to get the same effect of the Newsstand application of iOS 7 and iOS 8.

I'm using Xcode 6 (Objective-C)

Regards.

Comment: I get what you wanna do I think! took me a while. consider rewriting the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an iOS 7 App make itself transparent to see a user's home screen image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019031/how-can-an-ios-7-app-make-itself-transparent-to-see-a-users-home-screen-image)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I get it you want a transparent view i app like weather or safari, then there is NO public API as of yet