# How do I import the iOS Home Screen background and Blur it into my Application like on FaceTime?

Tags: ios, xcode

So in some of Apple's apps such as FaceTime or reminders, the background of the app is a blurred version of the user's wallpaper. Is this a private API or can we (as developers) use it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html

Comment: That's just blurring the view behind the current view. I would like to get the home screen background, not the view behind it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an iOS 7 App make itself transparent to see a user's home screen image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019031/how-can-an-ios-7-app-make-itself-transparent-to-see-a-users-home-screen-image)