# Make app background transparent

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I trying to figure out how to make an app transparent. In the weather app on the iPhone they have a table view that is completely transparent were you can see the user current iPhone background. I searched on how to do it but no luck. However I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019031/how-can-an-ios-7-app-make-itself-transparent-to-see-a-users-home-screen-image) on stack overflow the only thing is that its really outdated. I wanted to know if this is possible now without a private API. Here is a screen shot of what I'm talking about.

[image]
[image]

You can see that the weather app is using my current iPhone background as the their background. I tried setting the view to clear color but always end up with a complete black screen. Would really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: read also through all the comments on the answer.. it was private and may not work anymore -- there is no public api

Comment: Reduce opacity it will make app transparent

Comment: @Daij-Djan I've read the comments. I've tried some of the methods but no luck still. Also those question were ask like 4 years ago so I'm not sure. How would you be able to do this or is this an advance topic? Cause I am new to coding.

Comment: @AshokLondhe I've tried setting the opacity, but I keep getting a black screen.

Comment: Read some where that it was removed from IOS7.

Comment: I think you just need to set background image to UIView and then need to add UI element on it

Comment: I have recently done it.

Comment: then show us how ashok. above comment made NO sense im afraid. my vote is that it still valid what was said 4 yrs ago - which is why I closed this :)